# Element-wise multiplication of matrices with different dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I am interested in efficient element-wise multiplication of matrices with different dimension. Here is my solution:

Matrix 1 with `dim = {3, 4, 4}`

```
mat1 = RandomInteger[10, {3, 4, 4}]
(*{{{6, 0, 0, 3}, {3, 7, 6, 4}, {0, 4, 9, 3}, {6, 9, 3, 0}}, {{1, 7, 1, 
   4}, {3, 7, 6, 2}, {3, 6, 1, 9}, {3, 6, 4, 1}}, {{1, 7, 1, 0}, {4, 
   3, 9, 2}, {9, 10, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 2, 8}}}*)
```

Matrix 2 (dimension `{4, 4}`):

```
mat2 = RandomInteger[10, {4, 4}]
(*{{9, 3, 8, 6}, {2, 0, 2, 5}, {9, 8, 5, 9}, {10, 5, 2, 10}}*)
```

To let each element in `mat2` times with the element in the "subset matrix " of `mat1`, because the subset has same dimension i.e. `{4, 4}` in this case, so the element-wise multiplication is legal:

```
Result = Table[mat2 * mat1 [[i]], {i, 1, 3}]
(*{{{54, 0, 0, 18}, {6, 0, 12, 20}, {0, 32, 45, 27}, {60, 45, 6, 0}}, 
   {{9, 21, 8, 24}, {6, 0, 12, 10}, {27, 48, 5, 81}, {30, 30, 8, 10}},
   {{9, 21, 8, 0}, {8, 0, 18, 10}, {81, 80, 5, 27}, {20, 15, 4, 80}}}*)
```

but I don't know if there is a better way to do this, especially in terms of achieving better efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may `Compile` the code into a listable `CompiledFunction` as follows:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 2}, {b, _Integer, 2}},
   a b,
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

Here is a comparison

```
n = 100000;
m = 16;
mat1 = RandomInteger[10, {n, m, m}];
mat2 = RandomInteger[10, {m, m}];


Result = Table[mat2*mat1[[i]], {i, 1, Length[mat1]}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Result2 = cf[mat1, mat2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Result == Result2
```

> 0.342
>
> 0.067
>
> True

Comment: Thanks for the powerful answer!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This is genius. `mat1` is a rank-three tensor, and this code relies on the rank-2 tensor pattern in the argument of `cf` binding more strongly than the listability of the arguments, thus splitting `mat1` into a list of rank-two tensors but seeing `mat2` as a single rank-two tensor (matrix), not a list of rank-one tensors (lists). In this way threading over the list of matrices `mat1` works beautifully.

Comment: Yeah. In this sense, `CompiledFunctions` work slightly differently but IMHO more predictably than conventional function with the attribute `Listable`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map`:

```
Result = mat2*# & /@ mat1
```

This can be parallelized for large systems:

```
Result = Parallelize[mat2*# & /@ mat1]
```

Comment: Have you really tried and timed the parallelized code? On my machine and with the example from my post, your parallelized code needs about _15 times longer_ than `mat2*# & /@ mat1`...

Comment: Yes @HenrikSchumacher I have found the same bizarre result as you. Plus, none of my methods are as fast as yours.